# Function average and stdDev const int tab[ ]. Average problems

Tags: c, function

I have to use:
float average(const int tab[], int size);
float stdDev(const int tab[], int size);
to printf average and stdDev in C.

I have problem with average and i think with const int.
When i add const int tab[101] i have error with a1;
So how can i make it work with const int (if i can).
And if it is anything wrong with this code.
Any help will be helpful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float average(const int tab[], int size);
float stdDev(const int tab[], int size);

int main()
{
float ave, std;
int a1;
int j;
int tab[101];
printf("Podaj liczby: ");
for(j=0; j<=99; j++)
{
    a1 = scanf("%d", &tab[j]);

    if(a1<1)
 {
    printf("Incorrect input");
    return 1;
 }
 if(tab[0]==0)
 {
    printf("not enough data available");
    return 2;
 }
    if(tab[j]==0)
    {
        break;
    }

} 

ave = average(tab, j);
printf("%.2f\n", ave);
std = stdDev(tab, j);
printf("%.2f", std);
return 0;
}

float average(const int tab[], int size)
{
int i;
float y=0, x;

if(size<=0)
{
    return -1;
}

for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{

    x = x + tab[i];
}
y = x/size;
return y;
}
float stdDev(const int tab[], int size)
{
int i;
float y, z, z1, z2=0, z3=0;
if(size<=0)
{
    return -1;
}

y = average(tab, size);


for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{

    z = tab[i] - y;
    z1 = pow(z, 2);
    z2 = z2 + z1;
    z=0;
    z1=0;
}
z3 = sqrt(z2/size);
return z3;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles just fine, what is the error you want to solve? It will not run fine though, because you are using `x` uninitialized.

Comment: I use in school special program to check my work and it sometimes do error.
np enter 7 0
ave 116671774720.00⏎
std 0.00
I dont know why

Comment: I think a problem is that i have to add const int tab[101] but this doesnt work good

Comment: No, it is completely unrelated, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You define the variable `x` in `average` here:

```
float y=0, x;
```

without giving it a value. Then here:

```
x = x + tab[i];
```

you are reading its value without setting it anywhere beforehand. Because you never gave `x` a value, its value will be indeterminate and reading it will cause undefined behavior, which means that your program could e.g. print garbage output.

Always initialize your variables:

```
float y=0, x=0;
```